# Solar powered bilge pump

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, controller

Thanks in advance for any assistance you provide.

My system does everything correctly as expected, but its performance is abysmal.  The lift of the pump is very poor, it manages about 50cm before cutting out and the best flow I can get is far less that the pumps rating, I'm guessing a litre/minute.  The system spends more time charging the battery than it does pumping water during daylight hours.
The controller has an extra input for another solar panel, and a friend has some old panels they can give me, but they live 100km away, so haven't been able to explore this angle of improvement.

I haven't measured pump flow, pump current or voltage, so apologies in advance

The components are below

Lithium Battery
https://www.solarking.net.au/batteries/lithium-battery-cb-7-12-5

Solar Panel
https://www.supercheapauto.com.au/p/kt-cables-kt-cables-12v-40w-solar-panel/572271.html

Controller
https://www.kogan.com/au/buy/wholesalegateopeners-1224v-10a-solar-regulator-black-casing-reg10abkk/

Bilge pump.
https://www.bcf.com.au/p/bowline-500gph-bilge-pump/563499.html

Float Switch
https://www.bcf.com.au/p/blueline-automatic-float-switch/329215.html

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd want to first work out the energy required to move the amount of water you require each day. This is just mass times height times 'g'. (The mass is related directly to the volume, so this is rather easy to calculate.) Once you know the energy per day then you can work on sizing the solar cells and battery system. So how much water do you have to move, each day? That's question #1. And, what's the average height and what's the worst-case height involved, as well? That's #2. (I think I can guess at 'g', unless you live off-planet somewhere.)

Comment: Hi Jonk,  the pump is rated at 500gph which is far more than I need. Originally I replaced a 360gph pump, this gave me a little more lift than before, about an extra 10cm, which was enough to get my system at least doing something useful as now it reached the drain.  I am able to add an extra 150W of solar to the system when I get the panels from a friend.   I would have thought that once the battery is charged and the controller switches over to the load, the battery would be enough to supply the pump.  Something tells me it isnt enough.

Comment: A 10W panel is only about 0.01 hp, the pump peak current is a lot more than the average. Flow is probably rated with no lift and possibly tested at 14.2V no specs

Comment: Have you checked that the battery reaches a full charge with the charging system?  Will the pump work satisfactorily if you connect it directly to a fully charged battery? (you might even try using a standard 12v auto battery.) If a directly connected battery works well then the problem might be in the switching circuit or controller.

Comment: What is your exit pipe aperture?   If you have to pump from bilge over a gunwale, that's more lift than if  you pump from bilge over a gunwale and down a tube to below waterline (the weight of water in the down-tube gives a partial siphon effect).   Less height makes for less energy use per gallon.   The downtube, of course, has to be one-way only, will require a checkvalve or it will fill the bilge...

Comment: Good idea Nedd, I will disconnect the load from the controller and wait for it to fully charge and report back my findings

Comment: Whit3rd, the bilge is in a hole in the ground lined with a polyethylene barrel with holes in it and with particle filters preventing particles getting into the bilge, I'm draining a small swamp (10m2, 20cm deep)

Comment: Sorry Tony, my bad, it is a 40 watt panel, I have edited to fix my OP

Comment: @Mikesplace-ah, that's a problem that one often solves by planting a willow (or birch); a thirsty tree can do wonders.   Takes time, but very low electric consumption...

Comment: With all those rubbish equipment is a miracle that a pump even does one turn.

Comment: Hi Whit3rd, the swamp is a low point in my 3000m2 yard and after earthworks to fill it in and make everything flat, I am installing french drains that will come back to the sump with a pump.  So the pump will always be there and draining the yard during heavy rains that we get here in the subtropics (I live 1 hour north of Brisbane).  But yeah, I'm going to plant banana trees and other stuff to soak up the rain.

Answer (score 1):

The nameplate wattage of the pump is 27W. Your solar panel is rated for 40W, and it will only produce that for about 4 hours per day on a good day. So *ideally* your panel can run your pump for about 6 hours a day.

The cheapo charge controller will not 100% efficient and neither will charging and discharging the battery, so the actual run time will be less than that (maybe half? Just a guess). As for the pump not meeting its spec you will have to check the output voltage while the pump is running and ensure that it's at least 12V, it may not be due to the LiFe battery not being fully charged, or due to the batteries internal resistance. Adding a buck/boost regulator may be able to get you a steady 12V independent of the battery charge, but that will reduce the efficiency even more.

Comment: Thank you drew, I had the idea of getting my car battery directly connected to the pump for a test and I will get back to this post when i have done that

Comment: A car battery will also not necessarily be 12V. It's more like 12.6, and while the engine is running more like 13.8. You really need a volt meter.